# Passing Variables in C

Tags: c

I have a C program where I'm reading in from a file and then trying to print it to test it at the moment.  The thing i'm having issues is that my const in MAX = 40 and its printing that amount of times.  I've tried passing a reference to jobcount in the function but I get an error when I add * after int and an & before jobcount when passing it.  I appreciate the help, its always quality input on all issues!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct record{
  char name[1];
  int arrival_time;
  int job_length;
  int job_priority;
};

const int MAX = 40;

void fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX], int jobcount);
void output(struct record jobs[MAX], int jobcount);
int main(void)
{
  struct record jobs[MAX];
  int jobcount;
  fileinput(jobs,jobcount);
  output(jobs,jobcount);
  return(0);
}

void fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX], int jobcount){
  jobcount = 0;
  FILE *f = fopen("data.dat","r");
  while(fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d", jobs[jobcount].name, &jobs[jobcount].arrival_time, &jobs[jobcount].job_length, &jobs[jobcount].job_priority) != EOF)
    {
      jobcount++;
      printf("READ IN TEST \n");
    }
}

void output(struct record jobs[MAX], int jobcount){

  int j = 0;
  for(j = 0;j < jobcount; j++)
    {
      printf("%s %d %d %d\n", jobs[j].name, jobs[j].arrival_time, jobs[j].job_length, jobs[j].job_priority);
      printf("FOR LOOP TEST \n");
    }
}
```

data.dat looks like this

```
A1 3 3 3
B1 4 4 4
C1 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not get an error. Probably you might have changed in the forward declaration alone and forgot to change at the definition.

```
void fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX], int* jobcount);

fileinput(jobs,&jobcount);
```

And definition -

```
void fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX], int* jobcount) {
    // ....
}
```

Since `jobcount` is a pointer, you need to dereference first to modify/access the value it is pointing at. You need to post the exact error message for further help though.

Comment: This is the error I get.  gcc projectv2.c -o project
projectv2.c: In function ‘fileinput’:
projectv2.c:26:38: error: array subscript is not an integer
projectv2.c:26:60: error: array subscript is not an integer
projectv2.c:26:90: error: array subscript is not an integer
projectv2.c:26:118: error: array subscript is not an integer

Comment: @Intelwalk - As I mentioned earlier, you need to dereference the pointer. Array index must be an integer but what you are supplying is a pointer. So, you need to dereference `jobcount` before accessing like - `(*jobcount)` where ever you are using.

Comment: I get a segmentation fault now.  Here is my code :   #include <stdio.h>

struct record{
  char name[1];
  int arrival_time;
  int job_length;
  int job_priority;
};

const int MAX = 40;

void fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX], int* jobcount);
void output(struct record jobs[MAX], int jobcount);
int main(void)
{
  struct record jobs[MAX];
  int jobcount;
  fileinput(jobs,&jobcount);
  output(jobs,jobcount);
  return(0);
}

Comment: void fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX], int*  jobcount){
  *jobcount = 0;
  FILE *f = fopen("data.dat","r");
  while(fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d", jobs[*jobcount].name, &jobs[*jobcount].arrival_time, &jobs[*jobcount].job_length, &jobs[*jobcount].job_priority) != EOF)
    {
      *jobcount++;
      printf("READ IN TEST \n");
    }
}

Comment: Post your snippet at www.pastebin.com. Learn to use debugger to find where exactly it is failing.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the function to return an int and its all good now.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You would probably do best to revise `fileinput()` to return the job count:

```
int fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX])
{
    int jobcount = 0;
    ...
    return jobcount;
}
```

And then, in `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct record jobs[MAX];
    int jobcount = fileinput(jobs);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

The main alternative is to pass a pointer to `jobcount` to the `fileinput()` function.  This would perhaps be better if you also returned a status (all OK, too many entries in the data, bogus data, etc).  Your function would still return a value, but it would be the error indication, and the job count would be returned via the pointer.

A third (gruesome and not recommended) alternative is to use a global variable (or file static variable) for `jobcount`.

For a generalized input function, you should pass the size of the array explicitly, rather than assuming it is MAX:

```
int fileinput(struct record jobs[], size_t maxjobs);

int jobcount = fileinput(jobs, MAX);
```

You'd write the code to ensure that you do not exceed the specified number of job records.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN get "jobcount" from fileinput() withing a "return", if you want to.  You just need "&", passing in a pointer to "jobcount":

```
...
const int MAX = 40;

void fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX], int * jobcount);
...
int main(void)
{
  struct record jobs[MAX];
  int jobcount=-1;
  fileinput(jobs,&jobcount);
  output(jobs,jobcount);
  return(0);
}

void fileinput(struct record jobs[MAX], int * jobcount){
  *jobcount = 0;
  FILE *f = fopen("data.dat","r");
  while(
    (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d", jobs[jobcount].name, &jobs[jobcount].arrival_time, 
      &jobs[jobcount].job_length, &jobs[jobcount].job_priority) != EOF) &&
    (*jobcount < MAX) )
    {
      *jobcount++;
      printf("READ IN TEST \n");
    }
  ...
```